# FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2, ionic3

Estou obtendo seguinte erro:

> FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Consider adding
>   ".indexOn": "rota" at /motoristas to your security rules for better
>   performance

Regras do firebase:

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": "true",
        ".write": "true",
        ".indexOn": "gameSearching"
    }
}
```

meu arquivo.ts

```
initItems(serchQuery="gameSearching") {
return this.afDatabase.list('/motoristas', {
  query: {
    orderByChild: 'rota',
    equalTo: serchQuery
   }
 });
}
```

Comment: experimente incluir nas regras um índice em `nombre` na lista `/motoristas`. Aparentemente esse aviso está ocorrendo pois a consulta utiliza uma ordenação em um campo que não possui índices.

Comment: No caso tenho que colocar índice (nombe) na minha lista ?

Comment: deve ser algo como o que você já fez aqui `".indexOn": "gameSearching"`, mas para o campo `nombre`.

Comment: sou novo firebase, tem algum exemplo apenas da regra ?

Comment: Na doc oficial tem um exemplo simples https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data. No título "Indexing with orderByChild". Algo como `{"rules": {"motoristas": {".indexOn": ["nombre"]}}}` junto com suas outras regras deve resolver.

Comment: Obg funcionou, vou editar a pergunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conforme falamos pelos comentários, adicionar algo como:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "motoristas": {
      ".indexOn": ["nombre"]
    }
  }
}
```

nas suas regras deve resolver.

Fonte: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data